# How can I pass a form to a procedure as parameter and manipulate its properties?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Let's say I want to create a procedure in a unit I made that shows and hide forms by name (passed as parameter).

How could I do that and what's the syntax?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for something like: Popup(FormMy, 'Show'); from inside my Unit.

Comment: What is Popup?  And why don't you just write FormMy.Show?  I think you need to elaborate on your question in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm showing forms with messenger-like effects so I don't want to write the code for that in each form. That's why Popup is calling Form.Show but also placing the form in the right place and doing the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a procedure like this

```
procedure ShowMyForm(Form: TForm; Show: Boolean);
begin
  if Show then
    Form.Visible := True
  else
    Form.Visible := False;
end;
```

and call your form by `ShowMyForm(MyForm, True);` and be sure that your unit `uses Forms`

As David said you can make it

```
procedure ShowMyForm(Form: TForm; Show: Boolean);
begin
    Form.Visible := Show 
end;
```

Comment: @Bharat: You don't need a procedure for this, you just write MyForm.Visible := True

Comment: @David: You are correct but if I have multiple forms, for which i have to show/hide then it will be helpful.

Comment: @Bharat: No it won't. The routine as written is completely interchangeable with the Visible property. In fact you could write the body of your function as Form.Visible := Show which makes it clearer that it is nugatory.

Comment: @David Heffernan: How come? I have many forms with different names. The idea is to show several forms using the same procedure. MyForm.Visible := True is "hardcoded"

Comment: @emurad Why are you holding a list of form names? Why don't you hold a list of form instances? Then you can loop over the list and call Show on each member. Part of the problem answering this question is that you have not given enough information. To get a *good* answer you need to explain more. Why are you holding names rather than instances? How are the forms being created?

Comment: @David: You are correct in one point. I edited my answer. But as Emurad said we cant hard code for all the forms

Comment: @Bharat No, your edited function is completely interchangeable with direct use of the visible property. It's inputs are a form and the value of the Visible property. Exactly the same as direct use of Visible.

Comment: Actually what I was missing is this bit "Form: TForm" so your code did what I wanted to do but it's slow. When I click a button that invokes it the program freezes for about a second. Why and how can I solve this?

Comment: @emurad Could you post some more code, as an edit to your question. It's hard to guess what could be going on.

Comment: @emurad: It may be because of the code you are using in Show() or Activate() events.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the forms were created with the parent form as the owner [.Create(Self)], this should work:

```
procedure ShowFormByName(const ParentForm: TForm; const FormName: String; ShowForm: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to pred(ParentForm.ComponentCount) do
  begin
    if (ParentForm.Components[i] is TForm) and ParentForm.Components[i].Name = FormName) then
    begin
      if ShowForm then
        TForm(ParentForm.Components[i]).Show
      else
        TForm(ParentForm.Components[i]).Hide;

      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That code does now work, I think. I think you mean ParentForm instead of Component. Also the TForm case is not needed since the Name is introduced in TComponent if I recall correctly.

Comment: And I think you just can assign ShowForm to `ParentForm.Components[i].Visible`

Comment: @CodeInChaos you'd have to cast up to TControl at least

Comment: How can I call this function? I'm getting [DCC Error] UnitTest.pas(88): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean'

Answer (score 0):

You can loop around the CustomForms property (there are CustomFormCount of them) of the global Screen object.  This simply enumerates all the VCL forms in the app which may be what you want.

If you are looking for code it would be something like this:

```
for i := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount-1 do begin
  Form := Screen.CustomForms[i];
  if Form.Name=TargetName then begin
    DoSomething(Form);
    break;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetFormByName(const FormName: string): TForm;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    if SameText(Screen.Forms[i].Name,FormName) then
    begin
      Result := Screen.Forms[i];
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If the `FormName` is not found, this will return the last form in `Screen.Forms`. If you change the `Break` to `Exit`, and move the `AForm := nil` to the bottom, it should work.

Comment: @jasonpenny, you are right, thank you. I wrote the code fast, and didn't test it. I updated the post to fix that issue.